# Some tableview cell content disappears after scroll (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

Below is my custom cell class:

```
class AthleteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var myLabel1: UILabel!
var myLabel2: UILabel!
var profile: UIImageView!
var star = StarButton()
var touched = false

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:)")
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let gap : CGFloat = 10
    let labelHeight: CGFloat = 30
    let labelWidth: CGFloat = 150
    let lineGap : CGFloat = 5
    let label2Y : CGFloat = gap + labelHeight + lineGap


    myLabel1 = UILabel()
    myLabel1.frame = CGRect(x: gap, y: gap, width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight)
    myLabel1.textColor = UIColor.black
    contentView.addSubview(myLabel1)

    myLabel2 = UILabel()
    myLabel2.frame = CGRect(x: gap * 5, y: label2Y, width: labelHeight, height: labelHeight)
    myLabel2.textColor = UIColor.white
    myLabel2.textAlignment = .center
    myLabel2.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatMint()
    myLabel2.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    myLabel2.clipsToBounds = true
    contentView.addSubview(myLabel2)

    profile = UIImageView()
    profile.image = UIImage()
    profile.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.width - gap, y: bounds.height / 2, width: bounds.height * 1.25, height: bounds.height * 1.25)
    profile.layer.cornerRadius = (bounds.height * 1.25) / 2
    profile.layer.masksToBounds = true
    contentView.addSubview(profile)

    if (touched != false) {
        star.isSelected = true
        star.frame = CGRect(x: gap, y: label2Y, width: labelHeight, height: labelHeight)
        contentView.addSubview(star)
    } else {
        star.frame = CGRect(x: gap, y: label2Y, width: labelHeight, height: labelHeight)
        contentView.addSubview(star)
        star.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

}

and below is the method for creating my cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = AthleteTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")

    cell.myLabel1.text = "\(myArray[indexPath.row])"
    cell.myLabel1.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.myLabel2.isHidden = true

    cell.profile.image = UIImage(named: cell.myLabel1.text!)

    cellArray.append(cell)

    if (cell.touched) {
        cell.star.isSelected = true
    } else {
        cell.star.isOpaque = true
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2)

    return cell
}
```

and below is the method for selecting a cell which trips an animation that I would like the final state of to persist on the tableview cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    makeSelection(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
}

func makeSelection(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AthleteTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

    if(selectionArray.contains(myArray.object(at: indexPath.row))) {
        //Popping selection off of the stack and updating all labels
        updateLabels(tableView: tableView)
        selectionArray.remove(myArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.star.isFavorite = false
        cell.myLabel2?.isHidden = true
        //need to somehow implement all of the rank labels decreasing by one if I deselect someone
        cell.touched = false
        //updateLabels(tableView: tableView)
    } else {
        selectionArray.add(myArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.touched = true
        let rank = selectionArray.count
        cell.myLabel2.isHidden = false
        cell.myLabel2?.text = "\(rank)"
        cell.star.isFavorite = true
    }
}
```

This is a photo of what a cell looks like when you select it:

[image]

and this is a photo of that same cell after scrolling down so that is out of view and then scrolling back:

[image]

Something clearly goes very wrong here - I added that "touched" boolean to the custom table view cell class under the assumption that maybe the cells were being redrawn and there was no way for it to know whether it should have that star animated or not so it was considered nil but that fix doesn't seem to work (maybe I am onto something but implemented it incorrectly?)

Let me know if you have any clue what is going on here! thanks so much!!!

Comment: This looks like the classic cell-recycling bug.  `UITableView` doesn't keep cells around when they're off-screen, instead recycling them for re-use.  You can't store what is in effect model data in a the cells.

Comment: Ideally you should store the touched part in your datastore rather than in your cell. Your cell is not used for storing any information. So everytime your cell is clicked, you need to update your datastore for that particular item saying touched == true and then reload tableview.

Comment: @kapsym when you say "update your datastore for that particular item" what do you mean?

Comment: So you must be populating your table view using an array of objects right? That array of object is a datasource for the tableView. So if you have a custom object that represents your information that goes in ac ell, add touched parameter in that object. If you dont have a custom object, create one having name, touched etc as parameters. So when you do this selection, get the indexpath.row from the didselectCell method, Then go to your array and update that custom object for that particular position saying touched = true. And refresh tableview

Comment: @ S.Billings added the steps as an answer that points you on the right path. See if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a variety of problems. In your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, you should be calling `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`.

You should not be trying to read data from the cells in order to load content. You should save state data to a data model of some sort. An array works well for a table view with a single section, and an array of arrays works well for a sectioned table view.

There are countless tutorials on how to use table views. You need to go do some reading.

Comment: my tableview does have a single section. hence the array.

Comment: Ok, but your `cellForRow(at:)` method does not check your array of selected cells to see if it should set up the cell as selected or not. That in addition to not calling `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning it as an answer here as a step by step process

1) Create Struct for your data

```
struct Profile {
var personName: String?
var photoURL: String?
var rank: String?
var isTouched: Bool?

// add init method and stuff
}
```

2) Populate your array using these Profile elements. So that in the end you have an array of profiles.

3) Use this array to populate your tableview with each cell element getting data from the Profile object.

4) in your cellForRowAt method use dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:) to initialize your cell and assign values

5) if for that particular profile, isTouched is true then show

```
cell.star.isFavorite = true
```

else set it to false

6) in your didSelectRow, get indexpath.row and then in your array of profiles set Profile.isTouched=true/false based on your needs for that particular row and toggle accordingly. Update your profile array with new profile object.

7) refresh tableview.